# python regax [] does not work

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text

```
text = "السلام عليكم @%^ كِم مرُة قــــلتلكًة ل! لا لا آآآآآ إإإإ أأأأأenglish"
```

I want to remove all non-Arabic characters so I used the regular expression as

```
# replace all non-Arabic text
text = text.replace("[^ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكنهويىؤئء]","")
print(text)
```

However, this did not work with me, I also tried replacing some characters [أإآ] with "ا" but it also did not work with me

```
text = text.replace("[أإآ]","ا")
print(text)
```

I tried replacing single characters such as "ة" with "ه" and it worked. But the square brackets did not work, I even tried the English letters to check if the problem is because of the Arabic text but it did not work also.

Comment: `[^ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكنهويىؤئء]` is a regex, so use it with the appropriate `re.sub` method.

Comment: Use the inbuilt re module in python to solve this. re.sub(REGX_STRING,STRING_WITH_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO_REPLACE,STRING_FOR_WHICH_THIS_IS_APPLIED) aand the function returns the new string